# require file inside required file not working

Tags: php, file, require

I have some `require` "chain" in 3 PHP files. `index.php` requires `db_get.php`, which is requiring `db_cred.php`. All of them are in the **same directory**. 
These are the codes:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'db_get.php';
$db = getDatabase();
var_dump($db);
?>
```

---

**db_get.php**

```
<?php
require 'db_cred.php';

function getDatabase()
{
    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = $db_name;
    $username = $db_user;
    $password = $db_pass;

    $connectionString = 'mysql:host=' . $host . '; dbname=' . $database . '';
    $attributes = array(
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
        \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, 
        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'set names utf8mb4'
    );
    return new \PDO( $connectionString, $username, $password, $attributes);
}
?>
```

---

**db_cred.php** (this file is auto-generated by another PHP file)

```
<?php $db_name="testdb"; $db_user="qNOSdZ"; $db_pass="cAHk8A"; ?>
```

---

The error I got from **index.php** :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\sipil\me\db\db_get.php on line 7
Notice: Undefined variable: db_user in C:\xampp\htdocs\sipil\me\db\db_get.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined variable: db_pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\sipil\me\db\db_get.php on line 9
```

Why am I getting these errors ? All those files are in the same directory..
I may be dumb, this problem has taken me for awhile, please help.

Comment: `$db_name/db_user/db_pass1` are undefined in your getDatabase() function - they're not defined at all, or you've forgotten to make then `global`. If you were to require(db_creds.php) inside your getDatabase function, it'd all work.

Comment: but it is already defined in `db_cred.php`.. The problem is, why `db_get.php` can't get those variables ?

Comment: your issue is [variable scope - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). variables defined outside a function are not accessible inside the function unless you add them as function parameters, or define them as global inside the function, or as Mark B suggests move your `require 'db_cred.php';` inside your function.

Comment: you need to learn about PHP variable scope.

Comment: maybe `global $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass` will fix it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thank you very much all, I changed the location of `require` to inside the `getDatabaseFunction` and it works ! The solutions on the answers below also works, too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getDatabase()
{

    global $db_name;
    global $db_user;
    global $db_pass;

    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = $db_name;
    $username = $db_user;
    $password = $db_pass;

    $connectionString = 'mysql:host=' . $host . '; dbname=' . $database . '';
    $attributes = array(
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
        \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, 
        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'set names utf8mb4'
    );
    return new \PDO( $connectionString, $username, $password, $attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the above comments, solution should be:

```
<?php
require 'db_cred.php';

function getDatabase()
{
    global $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass;
    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = $db_name;
    $username = $db_user;
    $password = $db_pass;

    $connectionString = 'mysql:host=' . $host . '; dbname=' . $database . '';
    $attributes = array(
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
        \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, 
        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'set names utf8mb4'
    );
    return new \PDO( $connectionString, $username, $password, $attributes);
}
?>
```